# Generic way to handle all type of responses in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, fragment

> I have created a **Generic Fragment** class to handle all type of responses from server. I want to do some sort of **DataTableProvider<*>** to hanle any type of response.

How could I achieve this.

```
class TestFragmentActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DataTableProvider<Any> {

    protected val mTabPatientsFragment = TabPatientsFragment()
    protected val mTabObservationsFragment = TabObservationsFragment()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_fragment)

        replaceFragment()

    }

    private fun replaceFragment(){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,
            mTabPatientsFragment).commit()
    }

    override fun getDataTableListener(mTableFragment: DataTableFragment<Any>): DataTableListener<Any> {
        val dataTableId = mTableFragment.dataTableId
        if (dataTableId.equals("observations"))
            return mTabObservationsFragment
        else return mTabPatientsFragment
    }

    override fun getDataTableConfig(mTableFragment: DataTableFragment<Any>): DataTableConfig {
        val dataTableId = mTableFragment.dataTableId
        val config = DataTableConfig()

        config.noRecordCell = R.layout.cell_no_record
        config.showSearch = false
        config.showAddButton = false

        if (dataTableId.equals("observations"))
        {
            config.cellResourceId = R.layout.home_observation_cell
        } else config.cellResourceId = R.layout.home_patient_cell

        return config
    }

}
```

`getDataTableListener` callback in above fragment has error **type mismatch required DataTableListener found TabObservationFragment**

**TabObservationFragment**

```
class TabObservationFragment : AppBaseFragment(),DataTableListener<Observation>
```

**TabPatientFragment**

```
class TabPatientFragment : AppBaseFragment(),DataTableListener<Patient>
```

How could I set it to work for all type of responses.

I tried **DataTableListener<*>** but could not achieve

The error states

> **projections are not allowed for immediate arguments of a supertype**

How could I use DataTableProvider<*> to work for all type of responses

**Edit**

I have couple of fragment with fragmentViewpager inside TestFragmentActivity .

I have got a structure that helps to implement pagination ,search and implement everything in a fragment. But according to that structure  DataTableProvider must be handle in activity and basis of tableId I updated callback of `getDataTableListener` and `getDataTableListener`

The above callback should return some type of

> **Is there a way to achieve callback like below**

```
override fun getDataTableConfig(mTableFragment: DataTableFragment<*>?): DataTableConfig?

override fun getDataTableListener(mTableFragment: DataTableFragment<*>?): DataTableListener<*>?
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, use "out" modifier:

```
fun getDataTableListener(mTableFragment: DataTableFragment<Any>): DataTableListener<out Any>
```

Long answer:

What you are looking for is variance, which can you read about in official kotlin docs:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Because for example List interface looks like this:

```
public interface List<out E>
```

You can do assigement like this:

```
val list: List<Any> = listOf(1,2,3)
```

But it is not possible to do:

```
val mutableList : MutableList<Any> = listOf(1,2,3)
```

Because MutableList doesn't have "out" modifier. It makes sense, because MutableList can be changed, to MutableList you could add for example String, but it already points to List.

In your example you can use "out" modifier, if, and only if, your DataTableListener doesn't use generic type as input. For example:

```
interface DataTableListener<T>{
    fun assignValue(t:T)
    fun getValue():T
}
```

With interface like above, you still could use "out" modifier in your function, but you won't be able to execute "assignValue" function.

Whole example:

```
class Patient
class Observation

class DataTableFragment<T>
interface DataTableListener<T> {
    fun assignValue(t: T)
    fun getValue(): T
}

class TabObservationFragment : DataTableListener<Observation> {
    override fun getValue(): Observation {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun assignValue(t: Observation) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

class TabPatientFragment : DataTableListener<Patient> {
    override fun getValue(): Patient {
    }

    override fun assignValue(t: Patient) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

val mTabObservationsFragment = TabObservationFragment()
val mTabPatientsFragment = TabPatientFragment()

fun getDataTableListener(mTableFragment: DataTableFragment<Any>): DataTableListener<out Any> {
    val test = "observations"
    if (test == "observations")
        return mTabObservationsFragment
    else return mTabPatientsFragment
}

fun getIt() {
    val listener = getDataTableListener(DataTableFragment())
    listener.assignValue("test")
}
```

Comment: I have tried added out but not working . See Edit section in my question

Comment: Could u provide simplified version of your problem? Something that I could paste into IDE and compile? Out should do the trick, like I showed in "whole example". This code is compiling and you can check differences with yours.